# FeathersJS Inserts 2 records into MySql from 1 REST call

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-hook

When I use the .create(item) method to do an INSERT from the client (within the browser) I see 1 call via websocket or REST go to feathersjs. I see one request go into Feathersjs. For an unknown reason I see 2 rows created in MySql and 2 lines in the log that say: {"message":"after: name_of_service - Method: create","level":"info"}

Using sequelize 4.42.0 and feathers-sequelize 6.0.1

I do not have the issue when running create() from within the server code, only from client.

I found https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb/issues/80 that looked simular but is for a different DB and the explanation did not fit with MySql.

I switched to MariaDB for other reasons but obviously nothing changed.

I was using FeathersJS v3.x and upgrading to v4.x to see if that would fix it. Nope. As I work around I have been making my own insert methods but it would be nice to use the built in ones.

I tried switching between REST and websocket.

My Hooks:

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ ], // authenticate('jwt') normally use, but deactivated to debug
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Service:

```
const createService = require('feathers-sequelize');
const createModel = require('../../models/name_of_service.model');
const hooks = require('./name_of_service.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {
    const Model = createModel(app);
    const paginate = app.get('paginate');

    const options = {
    Model,
    paginate: {
        default: 100,
        max: 2000
    }
    };

    app.use('/name_of_service', createService(options));

    const service = app.service('name_of_service');

    service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

I expected it to insert 1 row in MySql table. But got 2. I expected one row in the log for the after hook, but see 2. This has been happening for a couple of months and was thinking, hey, maybe I am not the only one.

Comment: what does your client call look like?

Comment: I see the duplicity with inserts: 

 `this.get().client.service('order_notes').create(obj)`

and updates

  `this.get().client.service('order_notes').patch(this.get().order_notes.id, obj)`

Client side only sends 1 request.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. I found the issue. 
I fixed my rooky mistake by changing:

```
app.configure(socketio());
app.configure(socketio(function(io) {io.sockets.setMaxListeners(555);}));
```

To:

```
app.configure(socketio(function(io) {io.sockets.setMaxListeners(555);}));
```